# escaping character in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I can use the symbol @ while using \ character in C# like..

```
string str = @"\\190.168.0.100\New\XYZ";
```

Is there any corresponding character present in **JavaScript** ?

Comment: Why do you need to escape your string here?

Comment: @Michael Robinson because it has backslashes in it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get a literal `\` when making a literal string in JavaScript is to escape it.

```
var str = 'C:\\path\\to\\somewhere\\on\\windows.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character should work in JavaScript.